# Can a 2d array be created without static initializers?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I want to have an object that takes a course that a student has completed, but the student can take a course 3 times if they did not pass on their first attempt, basically an array of arrays, for example:

```
["F", "A", " "]//This means that the student took the course twice because they failed on the first attempt and because they passed on their second, the third string remains null
```

This is how I initialized the "CompletedCourses" variable in the Student class

```
public string[,,] CompletedCourses
```

And this is the constructor

```
public Student(string StudentID, string Name, string Status, Enum StudentMajor, string[,,] CompletedCourses)
    {
        this.StudentID = StudentID;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Status = Status;
        this.StudentMajor = StudentMajor;
        this.CompletedCourses = CompletedCourses;
    }
```

This is what the object is supposed to achieve.

```
Student student = new("00069110", "Erling Haaland", "Full-time", Majors.Computer_Information_Systems, new string[,,]//These are the courses completed and grade(s) achieved in them.
{  
    {{"CS50"},{"F", "B+", " "}},
    {{"Psychology 101"}, {"A", " ", " "} }//This is my idea of storing the courses a student has completed and the grade(s) they received in the courses.
});
```

The code above, I don't believe is the correct syntax for a multi-dimensional array, but I think it can be a guide to what the expected outcome is.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a multidimension array for this. At the _most_ it seems like a Dictionary is more appropriate. Can you give more context about what you're doing?

Comment: Why not using a class to store the courses along with grades? Keep it simple

Comment: Other much bigger problems aside (since they have been mentioned by other users), the immediate reason your code doesn't work is because multidimensional arrays in C# require that all dimensions have the same length. You can't have both a length 1 array `{"CS50"}` and a length 3 array `{"F", "B+", " "}` in the same dimension. It has nothing to do with static initialisers, really.

Comment: @gunr2171 basically I'm trying to have an array that stores the courses a student has completed, and each of those courses should have its own array to store the grades in.

Comment: Try: `public Dictoonary<string, List<string>> CompletedCourses;`. The key is the course name and the value is a `List<string>` with their results. Remwmber a list can have zero or many elements, easy to add new ones.

Comment: @PoulBak I have your solution in my program, but can you show an example of how you would initialize the object in the constructor?

Comment: Just use `new()`. BTW: You need to replace your array with the Dictionary everywhere.

Comment: Oops, typo: Dictoonary should of course be: `Dictionary`.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the word "static" here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate reason your code doesn't work is because multidimensional arrays in C# require that all dimensions have the same length. You can't have both a length 1 array `{"CS50"}` and a length 3 array `{"F", "B+", " "}` in the same dimension. It has nothing to do with static initialisers, really.

Since you just want a collection of courses and their grades, you can create types to model those things:

```
enum Grade {
    NotTaken, // could also be modelled with null instead, if you use Grade?
    Fail,
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E
}

record CompletedCourse(string name, Grade[] grades);
```

Then the constructor of `Student` could take a `List<CompletedCourse>`. Example usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Student( // omitting other arguments of the Student constructor
    new() {
        new("CS50", new[] { Grade.Fail, Grade.B, Grade.NotTaken }),
        new("Psychology 101", new[] { Grade.A, Grade.NotTaken, Grade.NotTaken }),
    }
));
```

Alternatively, if you want to easily search a course's grades by the course name, you can use a `Dictionary<string, Grade[]>` instead, in which case the inline initialisation would look like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Student(
    new() {
        { "CS50", new[] { Grade.Fail, Grade.B, Grade.NotTaken } },
        { "Psychology 101", new[] { Grade.A, Grade.NotTaken, Grade.NotTaken } },
    }
));
```

Comment: I would prefer `List<Grade>` over `Grade[]` since it's very likely the list is going to change, which is what `List` is for.

Comment: @PoulBak from what I understand, there is a *fixed* number of exams in OP’s design (3), and they can either have a grade, or be not taken yet. This is why I chose an array.

Comment: @Sweeper, I've tried your solution and it seems to have worked there aren't any errors, but this method would still allow the traverse the array with a loop, right? Thanks for your answer, by the way, it has really cleared some things up for me.

Comment: @NewDev Yes, both ways allow you to traverse them with a loop.

Comment: I want to enumerate the dictionary elements with a foreach loop, however, I'm getting an error warning under the foreach keyword. This is the code `foreach(KeyValuePair<Courses, Grade[]> kvp in students)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1} " +kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}` The error reads `Cannot convert type 'type' to 'type'`. What's causing this?

Comment: @NewDev so you ended up using a `Dictionary<Courses, Grade[]>` instead of `Dictionary<string, Grade[]>`? The `WriteLine` call is incorrect - it should be a `,` before `kvp.Key`, not `+`. But I don’t think that would cause a type conversion error. The cause is somewhere else. I’d suggest asking another question with a [mcve] if you still cannot fix it.